# I need to get Public IPv4 address on response of newly created instance by this Lambda Function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am creating a instance using boto3 and i want to print the public ip Address on **response**. please assist to complete this code but the code keep shows error can someone help to correct this code to show print public ipv4 address

```
import boto3
import json
 
AMI = 'AMI'
INSTANCE_TYPE = 'INSTANCE_TYPE'
KEY_NAME = 'KEY_NAME'
REGION = 'REGION'
SUBNET_ID = 'SUBNET_ID'
SECURITYGROUP_ID = 'SECURITYGROUP_ID'
 

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=event['REGION'])

        
    instance = ec2.run_instances(
        ImageId=event['AMI'],
        InstanceType=event['INSTANCE_TYPE'],
        KeyName=event['KEY_NAME'],
        SubnetId=event['SUBNET_ID'],
        SecurityGroupIds = ['my-sg'],
        MaxCount=1,
        MinCount=1,
        InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior="terminate",
        TagSpecifications=[
        {
            'ResourceType': 'instance',
            'Tags': [
                {
                    'Key': 'Name',
                    'Value': 'my-instance'
                },
            ]
        },
    ],
    )
    print ("New instance created:")
    instance_id = instance['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']
    print (instance_id)
    
    for instance in instance:
    IP = instance.public_ip_address
    print(IP)
        
    return instance_id**
```

error message shown like this

```
errorMessage": "'str' object has no attribute 'public_ip_address'",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The public IP address will *not* be provided after `run_instances()` because it takes a while to assign to the instance.

You should repeatedly call `describe_instances()` until a public IP address is provided. I would recommend waiting a few seconds between each call.

After calling:

```
response = describe_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id])
```

you can check if a value is provided:

```
instance = response['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]

if 'PublicIpAddress' in instance:
    public_ip = instance['PublicIpAddress']
```